# How can I convert a Data Frame to {"key":"xxxx","value":"xxxx"} structure?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have a Data Frame as follows:

```
    id name   dob 
0   1  Joe    16 Jun 1999  
1   2  John   04 Aug 1997
```

Now I want this data frame to be transformed as follows:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": "Joe"
                },
                {
                    "key": "dob",
                    "value": "16 Jun 1999"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": "John"
                },
                {
                    "key": "dob",
                    "value": "04 Aug 1997"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried the following code. It's working fine. I'm getting my desired output. But I'm trying to figure out if there's an easy way to do it, you know less code and more efficiency.

```
import pandas as pd
def transform(row):
    op = {}
    op["id"] = row["id"]
    op["attributes"] = []
    for col in cols:
        op["attributes"].append({"key":col,"value":row[col]})
    
    return op
data = [{"id":"1","name":"Joe","dob":"16 Jun 1999"},{"id":"2","name":"John","dob":"04 Aug 1997"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = df.columns.delete(0) #deleting id column
op = {"items":df.apply(transform, axis=1).tolist()}
print(op)
```

Can anyone has any ideas?

Comment: @sushanth Updated what I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can give it a try, using `list comprehension`

```
dict_ = df.set_index('id').to_dict(orient='index')

items = {"items": [
    {"id": k, "attributes": [{"key": i, "value": j} for i, j in v.items()]}
    for k, v in dict_.items()
]}

print(items)
```

---

```
{'items': [{'attributes': [{'key': 'name', 'value': 'Joe'},
                           {'key': 'dob', 'value': '16 Jun 1999'}],
            'id': '1'},
           {'attributes': [{'key': 'name', 'value': 'John'},
                           {'key': 'dob', 'value': '04 Aug 1997'}],
            'id': '2'}]}
```

Comment: Is there any other way where we can do this without a loop?